# How to send a message from an ASP.NET Web Forms app to an Azure function using Azure SignalR service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, azure-functions, signalr

I already created some simple Azure functions and created a signalR.

This is the server code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService;

namespace TaskOneSignalRService
{
    public static class Functions
    {
        [FunctionName("negotiate")]
        // used to send the url and the SAS token that will be used by the client to connect to the signalR service 
        public static SignalRConnectionInfo GetSignalRInfo(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequest req,
            [SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "signalRHub")] SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo, ILogger log) // injection of signal R 
        {
            // when we send an htpp request we will have the signalR address to access it 
            log.LogInformation("Running Connection:" + connectionInfo.Url + " " + connectionInfo.AccessToken);
            return connectionInfo; // the resourse 
        }

        // Receives a chat message in the request body and uses the SignalR output binding to broadcast the message to all connected client applications.
        [FunctionName("Broadcast")]
        public static Task SendMessage(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] object message,
            [SignalR(HubName = "signalRHub")] IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages,ILogger log)//binding the signalR message 
        {
            log.LogInformation("Message:" + message.ToString());
            
            return signalRMessages.AddAsync(
                new SignalRMessage
                {
                    Target = "newMessage", //target all 
                    Arguments = new[] { message } // we add the message in the arguments of the output of signalR
                });
        }
    }
}
```

but now I want to know what to add in the client side which is simple a text bar and button to send the message.

This is the button and the text code in the ASP.NET Web Forms app

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

What can I add here?

Comment: Can you tell us why you're using SignalR -- I mean, are you trying to update portions of the razor page and you want to do it with SignalR?

Comment: @mason yeah man I made an error I meant asp.net web Forms

Comment: @SuLlewellyn well basically I started to learn SignalR service and I created this signalr triggered by azure function but my question is simply how to connect the client to the server ?
In other words how can I connect the ASP.NET Web Forms to my service to send a message to the service ?

Comment: @SuLlewellyn so my goal is to establish a communication between both sides to send messages